# Getting a specific value from my database with an operator

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to give my users a rank based on the amount of posts they posted. I made a database containing a rankName row with "beginner, novice, itermediate,... to master" and a minimum row with some numbers. I tried to compare the amount of posts ($qtyPosts) with the minimum rows.

For example: When a user has 9 posts, he gets the rank Novice (which has a minimum of 5 posts). 
This is the code i wrote for that.

PHP code

```
// calculate number of posts from user
$rowsPosts = $user->getQuantityOfPosts($userID);
$qtyPosts = 0;
foreach ($rowsPosts as $q) {
    $qtyPosts++;
}

//status

$conn = db::getInstance();

$rank = "";

$statementRank = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE rank.minimum >=       $qtyPosts");
$statementRank->execute();

   while($row = $statementRank->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
   $rank = $row['rankName'];
   }
```

HTML code

```
   <h3>Status: <?php  echo $rank;  ?></h3>
```

However, It doesn't post the right rank, instead it posts the latest one, "master". Anyone any idea?

Comment: I don't understand the logic here,  wouldn't a $qtyPosts of 0 return every rank with your SQL?   You have no order by or limits in your query...

Comment: In `$rank = $row['rankName'];`, `$rank` gets overwritten every time. Only last value holds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should have a `maximum` column as well in the table and change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM rank WHERE rank.minimum >= $qtyPosts AND rank.maximum < $qtyPosts
```

Since according to your current post, you'll get all the ranks with `$qtyPosts` > the minimun number.

Comment: Ok got it working thanks. `$statementRank = $conn->prepare("SELECT rankName FROM rank WHERE rank.minimum <= $qtyPosts AND rank.maximum >= $qtyPosts ORDER BY rank.minimum LIMIT 1");`

Answer (score 2):

Consider your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE rank.minimum >= $qtyPosts
```

If the user is at the lowest rank, then *all* ranks will be `>=` that user's post count.

You can keep the same logic, but simply add an order and limit.  Something like this:

```
WHERE rank.minimum >= $qtyPosts ORDER BY rank.minimum LIMIT 1
```

This would sort the ranks from lowest to highest and just select the first one.

Comment: I'll also bring up the point that you shouldn't be using a while loop if you're only looking to set a variable once.

Comment: @AmeBerckmans, Also, you don't need that `foreach` loop, simple `$qtyPosts = count($rowsPosts);` will do fine.

Comment: I tried your 'where' idea, however it shows the wrong rank. The rank "Novice" has a minimum of 5 posts," Intermediate" has 15 posts. The user for example has 9 posts, however he shows the "intermediate" rank.

Comment: @ArneBerckmans: What does it show?  How specifically does it fail?  When you try the same SQL query manually on the database, what are the results?

Comment: @ArneBerckmans: What is the actual data and structure of this `rank` table?  And what is the runtime value of `$qtyPosts`?